# PHP Login with MD5 Password?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an existing database with users, each users password is stored as an MD5 hash.

Im trying to create a login form using PHP (Which im very new too) only I cant seem to get it to work, I know my username and password is correct yet I still receive the error that its wrong, Have I got to convert my password input to MD5 before checking the username in the table?

I currently have...

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
```

If I echo my password its outputted as text not a hash

```
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];
```

Comment: Yes you must hash the input before comparing

Comment: did you hash your password before using in select?

Comment: *"Have I got to convert my password input to MD5 before checking the username in the table?"* yes you do

Comment: In addition, your code is vulnerable to sql injections. Use [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and prepared statements to bind variable input to queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to hashing your password before comparing to what you have on your DB, you really should add a "salt" into that password hashing. This "salt" is nothing more than a random arbitrary string that you concatenate to the passwords, and it will make your hashed password "unique". I mean, if someone knows what a md5('12345') is a string 'A', this salt will make your users' password '12345' as the string 'B' in your DB. Thus outsiders won't be able to identify them very easily. So I'd suggest that you hash your passwords with a custom function myHashMD5() that calls md5() adding the proper "salt".
Besides that, in mysql you should compare strings with the operator LIKE, and not =.
Also, I use the function http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php for avoiding SQL injection, and your code is vulnerable to it.

Comment: `you really should add a "salt" into that password hashing` - wrong, you should use bcrypt / scrypt for password hashing.

Answer (score 0):

You should compare the *hash* of the password with the *hash* stored in the database:

```
$hashedPassword = md5($password);
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this line to your code just next to `$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];`

```
$mypassword = md5($mypassword);
```